# Text blurry after enable Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 Canvas: one for Login, one for Register.

This is Canvas of Login:

[image]

When register button is clicked, i change and call Register Canvas:

[image]

But it gets blurry. I use same Unity config in both Canvas.

I disable and enable Canvas via C# script:

```
void TaskOnClick()
{
    CanvasLogin.enabled = false;
    LoginValue.text = "";
    PasswordValue.text = "";
    CanvasRegister.enabled = true;
}
```

The problem only occurs when I enable Canvas via command/script, if Canvas start enabled, the blurry dont occur.

Scale Config:

[image]

And it's funny that during the execution if I change the aspect of the screen and return, the text backs to normal...

> The problem is not with second canvas, the problem is when i enable it
>   via command/script

Comment: Are your anchors set? - this can help preserver aspect ratio on any changes

Comment: Have you tried setting your canvases to `Pixel Perfect`?

Comment: With pixel perfect, with no pixel perfect. The problem still... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this same problem and as this was the first result when I searched I'll add my answer. I had a `GameObject` with `Canvas` and `CanvasScaler` components.

I found that you if you disable / enable a `Canvas` at runtime you need to update the `CanvasScaler` too. In my case I disabled / enabled the `CanvasScaler` also. Setting any value on the `CanvasScaler` would probably set it to dirty and cause update.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is only with one of the canvases, you might want to check the attached [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) components. It seems like the scaling on the second canvas is not correctly configured. 
You can just copy all of the component's values from your first to the second canvas, with the dropdown menu from the little gear icon in the upper right corner of the component in the inspector window.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:
use gameobject.SetActive() instead of canvas.enabled